# Firebase Storage not able to install via Cocoapods

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-storage

I'm at a bit of a loss here, since I have been trying to install Firebase Storage for my project without any luck.

What happens every time I try to run the pod install, it gives me this message:

```html
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (4.2.0)
Using Bolts (1.8.4)
Using FBSDKCoreKit (4.18.0)
Using FBSDKLoginKit (4.18.0)
Using FBSDKShareKit (4.18.0)
Using FacebookCore (0.2.0)
Using FacebookLogin (0.2.0)
Using FacebookShare (0.2.0)
Installing Firebase 3.11.0 (was 3.11.0)

[!] Error installing Firebase
[!] /usr/bin/tar xfz /var/folders/87/3qtbnngd7xx3m9t30xwpb1vw0000gn/T/d20170110-3205-gwhcri/file.tgz -C /var/folders/87/3qtbnngd7xx3m9t30xwpb1vw0000gn/T/d20170110-3205-gwhcri

tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/var/folders/87/3qtbnngd7xx3m9t30xwpb1vw0000gn/T/d20170110-3205-gwhcri/file.tgz'
```

I have tried almost every thing I can think of, like reinstalling Cocoa Pods, trying to create new projects and pod files. The file Cocoa Pods is trying to open is no where to be found?

The weird thing is that installing all other kinds of pods works fine, like Facebook SDK and even other Firebase pods.

Does anyone have an idea on how to get this installed? Thanks!

Comment: Did you reinstall cocoaPods like this?  [sudo] gem install cocoa pods. If so, try a total install with gem uninstall cocoapods then install again.

Comment: Hey Jay. Yes I did - I also deleted the cache, rebooted and so on. Nothing worked :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone still having this issue, I narrowed it down to curl being outdated from my Anaconda installation. I just ran `conda install curl` and updated it. Now it works like a charm again...

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with the `tar` utility on your computer, or the default CocoaPods behavior when installing a tar ball.

`Alamofire` and the Facebook SDK are both `git` repos, while we ship Firebase as a tar ball. I assume any other "closed source" pod that ships this way will similarly break on your computer/CocoaPods installation.

Since this appears to only be your computer (I can't repro, for instance), I would try a different version of CocoaPods (possibly an older one, if you're on the newest), or ensure that you can create and then untar a `.tgz` file.

Also relevant because `tar` is hard: [xkcd.com/1168](http://xkcd.com/1168)

Comment: Thank you Mike - I can't seem to locate the problem no matter what I try. I can untar files with no problems and I have tried 5 earlier versions of CocoaPods. But I have installed Firebase manually and it's working for me. So I am happy so far :-)